# SASS relative url wrongly configured

Tags: reactjs, sass, routes

I am working on React project and I have a problem with pointing to the image assets from `scss` files with relative paths. In general, relative paths are working locally, but after deployment to github pages, the route to image assets lacks the `github repo name` part. I don't know if it's the webpack configuration issue or I am writing relative paths incorrectly.

Here is my folder strutcure

```
├───config
│   └───jest
├───public
│   └───assets
│       ├───css
│       ├───fonts
│       ├───images
│       │   ├───background
│       │   ├───icons
│       │   ├───illustration
│       │   ├───logo
│       │   └───projects
│       │       ├───one
│       │       └───two
│       ├───js
│       └───scss
│           ├───blog
│           ├───common
│           ├───default
│           ├───elements
│           ├───header
│           └───template
├───scripts
└───src
    ├───component
    │   ├───common
    │   ├───footer
    │   ├───header
    │   └───slider
    ├───elements
    │   ├───blog
    │   ├───common
    │   ├───portfolio
    │   ├───projects
    │   └───tab
    └───home
```

Example url path defined in scss file:

```
.big-center-circle {
    background: url("/assets/images/background/circle-1.svg") no-repeat center top,
}
```

Resulting route in deployment

```
https://username.github.io/assets/images/background/circle-1.svg
```

Desired route in deployment

```
https://username.github.io/repository-name/assets/images/background/circle-1.svg
```

I use `react-router-dom` for routing and relative paths work correctly in `jsx` files. I only have issue with urls in SCSS stylesheets.

Comment: Move `scss` inside `src`, then reference like this `assets/images/..`

Comment: After moving `scss` to `src` and changing reference to `assets/images/..` I get an error

```
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/index.scss)
Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/images/background/circle-1.svg' in 'folder-path\src'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I turned out that the url to asset should define relative path from the main `scss` file placed in `src` folder.